# Anaconda installation abort

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, miniconda, anaconda3

I am on Windows 11 22H2 version, my Anaconda installation is crushing at the license agreement page.

Here is my windows-log about this issue (installation file was downloaded several times):

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" Guid="{a0e9b465-b939-57d7-b27d-95d8e925ff57}" /> 
  <EventID>1000</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-13T12:14:51.6096214Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>10288</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="26560" ThreadID="6280" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>OveraLL</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2341519818-1887911357-1335432441-1001" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="AppName">Anaconda3-2023.07-0-Windows-x86_64 (2).exe</Data> 
  <Data Name="AppVersion">2023.0.0.0</Data> 
  <Data Name="AppTimeStamp">614f9f13</Data> 
  <Data Name="ModuleName">unknown</Data> 
  <Data Name="ModuleVersion">0.0.0.0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ModuleTimeStamp">00000000</Data> 
  <Data Name="ExceptionCode">c000041d</Data> 
  <Data Name="FaultingOffset">6985f3d0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessId">0x58c4</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessCreationTime">0x1d9b5838dcabafc</Data> 
  <Data Name="AppPath">C:\Users\Ruslan\Downloads\Anaconda3-2023.07-0-Windows-x86_64 (2).exe</Data> 
  <Data Name="ModulePath">unknown</Data> 
  <Data Name="IntegratorReportId">3df6358b-875d-414a-af83-bce2d9246fe2</Data> 
  <Data Name="PackageFullName" /> 
  <Data Name="PackageRelativeAppId" /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I had deleted path variables with my python (v. 3.11.4), java, toolbox, but it doesnt help.

I was trying to install miniconda too, result is the same.

I will be grateful for any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: What browser is your standard browser? This might be an issue with your browser failing to open a site (according to a quick google search for the ExceptionCode).

Comment: As this is not really a programming question, you might find better help on a windows specific forum.

Comment: @Dschoni I am using Google Chrome, version 114.0.5735.199

Comment: Default browser changed to Edge, but issue is still occured